# brain-teaser R problem - programming problem solving in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to solve a novel problem:

Given the following data:

```
S = c(19, 10, 12, 10, 24, 25, 22)
k = 4
```

I am trying to calculate a function. I want to print the maximal subset of `S` in which any sum of 2 numbers in `S'` is not evenly divisibly by `k`

So one answer might be `S' = [10, 12, 25]` and the other could be `S' = [10, 22, 24]`.

Another example:

if `S = {1, 7, 2, 4}` and `K = 3`

Then

```
1 + 7 = 8
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 4 = 5
7 + 2 = 9
7 + 4 = 11
2 + 4 = 6
```

That is `S' = {1, 7, 4}` and will never sum to a multiple of  `k = 3`

Comment: What code did you try? In any event -- there is a graph theoretic formulation of this. Sounds like a maximum clique problem. Here, the graph would be the one where two elements are connected by an edge exactly when their sum is not divisible by 3.

Comment: If you want help on your attempted solution, why not show that solution?

Comment: For people without Math/CS background, can you (or others) explain in simple English what *maximal subset* is?

Comment: @Shree OP probably wants a subset which has *maximum* size subject to the constraints -- one that is as large as possible. The word "maximal" isn't really appropriate here, since that would merely mean a subset with that property that can't be extended to a larger subset with the same property. A maximum set is maximal, though the converse can be false.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks a lot! So if I understand correctly, we have to find a subset with as many elements as possible such that given constraint is satisfied, right?

Comment: @Shree Correct. The Wikipedia article on [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) gives a general setting, although I suspect that in this special case modular arithmetic and perhaps gcds can be used to come up with more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a linear time algorithm for this. This algorithm is well explained by orezvani in this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/57876/39695) on Computer Science section of stackexchange.
I translated the orezvani pseudo code in R:

```
max_subset<-function(S,K){
  R <- S %% K
  Res <- c()
  for(k in 1:(ceiling(K/2)-1)){
    index_k = which(R==k)
    index_K_k = which(R==(K-k))
    if(length(index_k) >= length(index_K_k)){
      Res <- c(Res, S[index_k])
    }else{
      Res <- c(Res, S[index_K_k])
    }
  }
  print(R)
  Res <- c(Res, S[which(R==0)][1])
  if(K %% 2 == 0){
    Res <- c(Res, S[which(R==(K/2))][1])
  }
  return(Res)
}
```

I tried with different example:

- with `S <- c(1, 7, 2, 4)` and `K = 3` give `1 7 4`;
- with `S <- c(3, 17, 12, 9, 11, 15)` and `K = 5` give `11 17 12 15`
- with `S <- c(3, 7, 2, 9, 1)` and `K = 3` give  `7 1 3`
- with `S <- c(19, 10, 12, 10, 24, 25, 22)` and `K = 4` give `25 12 10`

In order to be more understandable I tried to be as similar as possible to the pseudocode, probably my solution could be optimized using R language specific features.